# Unknown wifi connection in my Connection dropdown menu

Tags: mac, wifi, malware

My problem is that I have this strange wifi connection name as shown in the attached image below among my wifi connections. Each time the name is different which is always a randomly generated haphazard mixture of letters and numbers. Is it possible that my system be infected with some malware. I have reinstalled the OS, El Captain, to get rid of this particular issue but at times I can still see the connection there. Do I need to worry about this?

[image: An image captured from my Wifi connection list]

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218295/unknown-wifi-connection-in-my-connection-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite *likely* (no guarantee) that there is someone nearby with a WiFi device (Phone, printer, WiFi 4G router, etc) that generates a different name each time it turns on.

Note that the signal strength is pretty low. so it is not likely all that nearby. Using a WiFi stumbler might give you more information about the device as most WiFi devices will often self-identify with a Manufacturers name or model number. The stumbler software could also potentially help you locate at least which direction the WiFi source is.

Is it possible that someone is nearby trying to hack into your systems? Yeah. Is it likely? No, unless you have a lot of money or have access to valuable information or goods, or a person of interest to someone gathering intelligence on you it is unlikely you are a persistent target of attack.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I think your explanation is most likely true about my situation. I only wonder what sort of device "generates a different name each time it turns on" and why?

Comment: The 'name' changes at each power-cycle to better eliminate the chances of several such devices self-advertising themselves with the same name, and to provide pretty good security with a 15 alphanumeric character string, upper & lower case.  It could be a wifi webcam, lighting/music control system; something that needs more range than bluetooth.